Let R be a relation on A. Suppose that A and R are the empty sets, then is R a reflexive relation on A?
Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. According to the definition of reflexive relation, $R$ is said to be reflexive on $A$ if for all $x \in A$, $(x,x)\in R$. This can be translated symbolically as $\forall x\in A (x,x)\in R$. This statement is logically equivalent to $\forall x ((x\in A) \implies ((x,x)\in R))$.
Now, let R be a relation on A and suppose that A and R are just the empty sets. Then, if I am not mistaken, the statements $x\in A$ and $(x,x)\in R$ will be false, right? So clearly, $R$ is reflexive on A?

Please do not answer in the comments.
